How to format a dialogue with quotes of poetry?
I'm working on a typeset of Dorothy L. Sayers' novel Clouds of Witness. Sometimes the characters will quote poetry when they're speaking:

'Hurray!' said Peter.
'Then downwards from the steep hill's edge
They tracked the footmarks small
(only they're largish).'

I have this rendered with LaTeX as:

This doesn't look right to me, though I can't work out why.
The line in parentheses is Lord Peter's own speech, not part of the poem he's quoting, so it seems like it should be on its own line, but it looks weird that it's not indented. The initial quote mark also looks weird off on its own, and I think there's too much space before and after the poem. How much space should there be?
Another example happens to follow on immediately from the first:

"No such luck," said Parker. "It's more a case of:
They followed from the earthy bank
Those footsteps one by one,
Into the middle of the plank;
And farther there were none!"


This looks even worse to me—I really hate the close quote having its own line—but I can't figure out what it should be.
A third example:

'Come on, gossiping old thing,' said Lord Peter unreasonably. 'This is a beautiful ditch.
From such a ditch as this,
When the soft wind did gently kiss the trees
And they did make no noise, from such a ditch
Our friend, methinks, mounted the Troyan walls,
And wiped his soles upon the greasy mud.
'Look at my trousers!'


This example has text before and after the quoted poetry, but I can't work out whether the dialogue after the poem ("Look at my trousers!") should be indented or not.
Chicago Manual of Style doesn't say, other than to say that two or more lines of poetry should be blockquoted.
Does anyone know?

The first inverted comma should definitely come at the beginning of the quotation, not floating on its own! Note that the last bit of verse is Peter's parody of 'On such a night as this' from The Merchant of Venice.

Typesetting an already published work for a republication
In your case, since you are typesetting a text from a published work, I would strongly recommend that you recreate the exact formatting from the original. I cannot find the first edition online, but the older printed editions that I have access to all render the passage like this:

As you can see,

the quoted text is rendered in italics (meaning that the passage in parenthesis isn't part of the poem, but a comment by the speaker),
the poem is indented and set off as a blockquote with one blank line above and below,
and each verse of the poem is given its own line.

The editions I have access to differ in whether the parenthetical comment is typeset as part of the blockquote (as in my example) or not (as in yours). If I am not mistaken, the editions that do not treat it as part of the blockquote are all public domain republications from recent years (such as you are probably planning), while the printed publications from earlier years all seem to treat the parenthetical comment as part of the blockquote. As there is an authoritative edition (i.e. the first edition from 1926), get a hold of it (in a public or university library) and typeset your text exactly as it was printed in the publication that the author of the work has approved.

Typesetting for a first publication
The convention I am following is to render dialogue the way you say and hear it. Do you say or hear numerical digits (e.g. the symbol 3)? No, you say and hear the numeral (e.g. the word three). So the convention is to write words instead of digits in dialogue. The only exceptions to this convention are to capitalize proper nouns (such as names: "Come on, Peter!"), to use italics for emphasis ("He did do it."), elipses for speech that fades away ("Should we really...?"), dashes for long pauses and breaks ("I am de—").
Following this convention, poetry is styled as running text in dialogue in prose fiction. Running text is the body of text in prose, in the form of sentences and paragraphs, as distinguished from headings, captions, footnotes – or verses in poetry.
Think about it. When someones speaks a poem, how do you recognize it as poetry? You don't see it broken into verses, so how can you still know that it is a poem? Because of the formal language, the rhythm, and the rhyme, of course. In spoken language, you don't need the linebreaks after every verse to understand poetry at all.
Following that convention, your example would be styled as:

'Hurray!' said Peter. 'Then downwards from the steep hill's edge they tracked the footmarks small, only they're largish.'

Depending on how long a pause you want before the last subordinate clause (that I took out of its parenthesis, because you cannot say or hear parentheses), you could also use a dash instead of a comma.
That is the convention. But some more recent texts break with this convention and use symbols in dialogue (such as numerical digits) and other "unspeakable" styles that are only visible in printed texts (capital letters, italics with other meanings than emphasis, quotation marks when the speaker quotes someone etc.). Following this new style you could represent poetry in verses in dialogue as well or replace the paragraph marks with dashes:

Hurray!' said Peter. ' "Then downwards from the steep hill's edge / They tracked the footmarks small / (only they're largish)." '

I find that unpleasant to read, both visually and cognitively (there is so much more information my brain needs to process, making reading more strenuous), but it is certainly possible today and would not seem odd.
What you want to do is your authorial decision.

The Chicago Manual of Style
The rule in the Chicago Manual of Style that two or more lines of poetry should be blockquoted refers to text outside of dialogue.
Generally, the CMOS should be consulted with caution, because it often does not distinguish between different types of writing and attempts to establish general rules that apply to all kinds of text. For fiction, it is always prudent to look in a couple of novels from the country, genre, and style you want to publish in to understand how fiction is printed than to blindly follow the CMOS.

I would consider
'Hurray!' said Peter. 'Then downwards from the steep hill's edge they tracked the footmarks small, only they're largish.'
i.e. Quote the poem inline but italicise it.
